# How to debug command line file with symbolic data

Tags: windows, debugging, fortran, windbg, gfortran

I have a compiled .exe file (compiled with gfortran and -g option) that crashes. I can attach the WinDBG program to it using the **WinDBG -I** command.

Funny enough it generates a *stack overflow*:

```
(38f0.2830): Stack overflow - code c00000fd (!!! second chance !!!)
```

However, the output says that there is no debugging information in my program. It tries to search for either .dbg or .pdb files but they are not there. I would assume debugging information is included in the executable (coming from a unix-background).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I circumvented the problem by starting the program via gdb. In this way, gdb will give an error and you can issue the backtrace command.

It's not perfect, so I'm open for better solutions, but this works for now.

Answer (score 0):

Debug formats are compiler specific, so you need to use a debugger that understands the format produced by your compiler. As by gfortran I assume you mean GNU fortran, this would be the [GNU gdb](http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) debugger.

Comment: I know gdb, so that would mean I have to change debuggers. The question is, how to get a crash dump that I can analyse with gdb?